# beginner Linq syntax and EF4 question

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

Question

With the following linq code snip I get a list of clients with address filtered by the specifications but the form of the entities returned is not what i had expected.

The data is 1 client with 2 addresses and 1 client with 1 address.

The query returns 3 rows of clients each with 1 address

- Client 1  =>  Address1
- Client 1  =>  Address2
- Client 2  =>  Address3

  ```
  var query = from t1 in context.Clients.Where(specification.SatisfiedBy()).Include("ClientAddresses")
              join t2 in context.ClientAddresses.Where(spec.SatisfiedBy())
              on t1.ClientKey equals t2.ClientKey
              select t1;
  ```

My expectation was a little more like a list with only two clients in it, one client with a collection of two addresses and one client with a collection of one address.

- Client 1  =>  Address1 / Address2
- Client 2  =>  Address3

What am I missing???

Thanks!

Comment: This gets closer.  This returns 3 clients but the correct number of addresses.    var query = from t1 in context.Clients.Where(specification.SatisfiedBy())
                        join t2 in context.ClientAddresses.Where(spec.SatisfiedBy()) 
                            on t1.ClientKey equals t2.Client.ClientKey into x
                        from t2 in x
                        select t1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try something like:
`query = query.Distinct();` ?

You might need to reveal how the specifications are written to give more data.

For example, I don't see why your query is not something like:

```
var query = from t1 in context.Clients.Include("ClientAddresses")
            where specification.SatisfiedBy() &&
                t1.ClientAddresses.Any(spec.SatisfiedBy())
            select t1;
```

#### Update

See if this works. Not sure how much of that is supported by EF. It's very similar to your oriignal query

```
var query = (from t1 in context.Clients.Where(specification.SatisfiedBy())
                 .Include("ClientAddresses")
             from t2 in context.ClientAddresses.Where(spec.SatisfiedBy())
             where t1.ClientKey == t2.ClientKey
             select t1)
            .Distinct();
```

Comment: The distinct works on my original query but produces a 50 line monster sql statement.  =(  The compound specification pattern (borrowed) works on IQuerable (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>) and t1.ClientAddress.Any() is IEnumerable. (Func<TEntity, bool>)  I have no idea how to make that work.

Comment: Regarding the monster query, did you try to see the execution plan or so? Sometimes the monster queries are not that bad (most times they are for sure).

Comment: See my update, regarding Any, I know there is IQueryable version of it. IS the model generated from EF or coded by yourself?

Comment: In fact, most likely you'll need to change the specification itself to support the call starting from "Client" (meaning support going through collections). Not something you'll want fo rsure.

Comment: Did you see Dynamic LINQ library if it helps at all? See http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: I did end up going with the distinct to further the effort.  The query it generates is almost scarry.  With the large databases we work with I'm very worried EF4 is not such a good idea.

Comment: I will check out the builders.  Thank you!

Comment: In fact, I like NHibernate 3.0 more, but when it comes to more than one table with criteria on each etc, I usually end up building a DB view, and adding some indexes to the fields I want to filter/sort by. This gave me dramatic performance fixes. I know in some places you may not have as much control over the DB as a dev though, but I assume if you can run queries like this without admin stopping you, then you probably have such control.

Comment: I know you already marked the answer as correct (thanks), but would love you to see the examples on this article.   
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx  
It shows how to do the "Any" parts with specifications-like expressions.